# What is a one-line expression for constructing a C++ tuple with an array (C or std::array) element?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdarray, stdtuple

I'd like to have a tuple that has an array element as a member. In particular, I'd like this array element to be 2D -- so any answer has to work for more than 1D. What I'd ideally like is something I can initialize with initializer lists, e.g. `std::tuple<ARRAY_TYPE, ...>({{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, ...)`.

It seems like such a tuple is very hard to construct, requiring manual initialization (i.e., for loops and the like). Here is what I've tried:

`std::tuple<int[M][N], ...>` -- this doesn't work because of limitations of C-style arrays. The tuple itself is a valid type, but initialization needs to be done manually (not at construction).

`std::tuple<std::array<std::array<int, M>, N>, ...>` -- I thought this would work, but for some reason, something like `std::tuple<std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>, ...>({{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, ...)` fails with a "no matching constructor error". It does work in 1D though.

`std::tuple<std::vector<std::vector<int>>, ...>({{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, ...)` actually *does* work, but vectors seem like overkill here

Any thoughts, SO? Is there any way I can get the C-style arrays to work? That would be ideal.

Comment: [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387) may be relevant, and is apparently expected in C++17.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need an extra pair of brackets `{}` around the array:

```
std::tuple<std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>, int> v({{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}}, 1);
                                                     ^                ^
```

This is because `std::array` is initialized using *aggregate-initialization*. It works with `std::vector` because there is `std::vector<std::initializer_list<T>` constructor (`std::array` does not have any constructors).

Comment: You are, of course, correct. Upvoted. Still wish C-style arrays would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::make_tuple`, example:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple<std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>>({{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}});
```

[edit]
My original suggestion was:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple<int[2][2], int>({{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 42);
```

But it's unsafe (first tuple element will be pointing to stack memory); see discussion below.

Comment: That is exactly what I want! And it works. But, is this safe? The return type is `std::tuple<int (*)[2], int>`.

Comment: My worry is that it returns pointers to the data in the std::initializer_list.

Comment: @user2333829 The inner type will be `int (*)[2]`, so it is not safe - Just try returning this from a function or copying such `tuple` and you will quickly see the problem.

Comment: Right, this is not safe, you still need to pass `std::array` as first param to make it safe. I am somewhat unhappy, that it passes through compiler without even a warning :/

Comment: edited, so bad solution won't be up top; thanks for spotting this - yet another way to be wary of C++ :( (upvotes to you both)

Comment: You shouldn't supply explicit template arguments to `make_tuple`, that's the kind of thing that can happen when you do. It's designed to be used with argument deduction.